# Dependencies between Managed Metadata columns

Tags: managed-metadata

I have two managed metadata columns, which I want to make dependent of each other. The first column is a set of companies (Company), and the other column contains the employees (Employee) of the companies. The problem is that these columns contain huge amount of terms. Thus, when you select a company (Company A), I want to limit the options for the second MMD-field to just contain employees for this specific company. Is this possible somehow?

The MMD-field Company contains all companies.
The MMD-field Employee contains all companies on the first level, and then all employees on the second level.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, look at [this jquery library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/). This library provides functionality to configure cascade drop down lists.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting every employee as a managed metadata item? 
It would be a better way to make a list where you add every employee in than add your metadata column company to every emoployee this way you can filter the list of employees on your metadata column country.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good link on Cascading Dropdown with Managed Metadata:

[SharePoint 2010 Cascading or Filtered Dropdowns](http://veerareddykolan.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-cascading-or-filtered.html)

Comment: Hi Welcome to SharePoint stack exchange. While the link you posted may theoretically answer the question, it is prone being broken. Please either bring the relevant fix in, or describe why it fixes the question. Refer to the [FAQ][1] for more information. [1]:http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq